# Hapi child plugin does not apply the parents route prefix

Tags: typescript, plugins, routes, prefix, hapi

**The problem:**
Hapi does not pass a plugins route prefix to its registered child plugins.

**What i did:**
I've got some plugins which i register with a route prefix in some kind of main plugin like this:

```
const plugin: Hapi.Plugin<any> = {
  name: 'public-api',
  version: '1',
  register: async (server: Hapi.Server, options: any) => {

    await server.register([{
      plugin: myPlugin,
      routes: {
        prefix: '/records'
      }
    }]);
  }
}
```

Now all the registered routes in 'myPlugin' get the prefix 'records'. So far so easy.
Let's assume i got some more plugins registered in the 'public-api' plugin.

Now in my main server object i register the 'public-api' plugin itself like this (besides some other third party plugins):

```
await server.register([
  ...thirdPartyStuff,
  {
    plugin: publicApi,
    routes: {
      prefix: '/api'
    },
  }
]);
```

**My expectation:**
The 'records' entity is now reachable by the following path: ***/api/records***
As the Hapi api docs specify, a registerd plugins route prefix will be passed or prefixed in its registered child plugins.
Ref: [Hapi register plugins](https://hapi.dev/api/?v=18.4.0#-await-serverregisterplugins-options)

**Reality:**
The server totally ignores the the prefix of the 'publicApi' plugin and makes 'myPlugin' available under ***/records***

**Call for help:**
So mybe i am just missing something or i am to stupid to properly read the docs.
Either way, maybe there is someone out there who can enlighten me, or even give a solution
to what i think should normally work :D

So thx in advance for reading my story and your help in any way!
Cheers!

Comment: Somebody? Anybody? :D
I feel like this feature is not commonly used.
But maybe someone feels like a good samaritan and can take a look at this.

Thx again

Answer (score 0):

I've read through the [docs from hapi](https://hapi.dev/tutorials/plugins/?lang=en_US) and created a working example based on your information and your mentioned desired behavior.

To run it just install ts-node and hapi in your typescript configured project directory.

```
import { Server, Plugin, Request } from 'hapi';

const recordPlugin: Plugin<any> = {
    name: 'my-plugin',
    version: '1',
    register: async (server: Server, options: any) => {
        server.route({ 
            method: 'GET', 
            path: '/records',
            handler: async function(request: Request, h: any) {
                return 'something';
            }
         });
    }
};

const init = async () => {

    const server = new Server({
        port: 3000,
        host: 'localhost'
    });

    await server.register({
        plugin: recordPlugin,
        routes: {
            prefix: '/api'
        }
    });
    await server.start();
    console.log('Server running on %s', server.info.uri);
};

process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => {

    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
});

init();
```

Though from my perspective, your problem is how you import and declare your plugin for the server.

Cheers!

Comment: Hey Max,
thx for taking a look a this. The way you suggested the solution is not what i had in mind.
You are setting path directly to /records when my attempt was to give the plugin itself a prefix that then gets extended by the parents prefix.

My plugin has several registered routes that i all want to make accessible through the prefix /records.

So this sadly this does not address the problem i have.

Cheers!